# How to deploy and use valgrind for embedded Linux?

Tags: linux, deployment, embedded, valgrind

After built valgrind for embedded Linux, it generated bin, include, lib, libexec, and share folders. It needs a lot of spaces. Which files should be transferred to embedded Linux system if I just want to run memcheck tool? Do I need to create the same path as the prefix such as /tmp/val and put the files in the path? I cannot put it in /bin or /usr/bin.